# How to soft import a module in a project in Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

I have 2 projects, MyLibrary, and MyProject. They each have their own repository. I want to develop and debug MyProject and MyLibrary together inside the same Android Studio window. I want to be able to add breakpoints inside MyLibrary and MyProject codes while I run my app. I tried using the Import module in Android Studio and it actually copied MyLibrary into MyProject repo. Is there any way I can just reference the MyLibrary as a directory path inside MyProject? So that I can commit my codes in their own repository?

Let's say my paths are:

MyLibrary - /Users/me/repo/MyLibrary

MyProject - /Users/me/repo/MyProject

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Add a module in your project repo, then configure its sourceSets (java, resources etc.) in module's build.gradle file to point to your library repo.

See [this](http://google.github.io/android-gradle-dsl/current/com.android.build.gradle.api.AndroidSourceSet.html). And then add a compile dependency for your prjects. perform a gradle sync and you should be good to go.

[image: Android sourceSets configuration]

Comment: Hi KKD, do you have an example? Let's say my paths are:

MyLibrary - /Users/me/repo/MyLibrary
MyProject - /Users/me/repo/MyProject

Comment: Check out the screen shot I attached with my answer

Comment: I don't think that screenshot helps clarify what needs to be done

Comment: All you need is the source and resources from your library module. In the new module that you add in you project repo in android studio, configure sourceSets i.e. java and resources in module's build.gradle file. Point it to "/Users/me/repo/MyLibrary/ {java, src and resources}". And this new module is a dependency in your main project.

Comment: Thanks drulabs, I got further but now I'm getting Error: Duplicate resources for res/values/strings.xml. Looks like MyLibrary res/values/strings.xml is conflicting with MyProject res/values/strings.xml.